# unauthorized_client when trying to exchange auth code for credentials

Tags: node.js, cordova, google-signin, google-authentication

After carefully following the instructions here on [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus), I successfully get the `serverAuthCode`, and send it to our server.

Then in our server we call:

```
function getGoogleToken(code) {
  const oauthClient = new google.auth.OAuth2({
    clientId: 'our ios app client id',
    redirectUri: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
  });
  return oauthClient.getToken(code) // the code that comes from ios
}
```

and that's where it fails with `unauthorized_client`.

Can I get some pointers here? I'll provide any extra details necessary.

Comment: Do you understand what "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" is for? https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app#creatingclient - I would update the question to show the entire OAuth 2.0 code flow. Their documentation on setting up OAuth is really poor so I do not know what you have configured or what code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a misunderstanding with the arguments that `OAuth2` expects. Here's the proper config:

```
function getGoogleToken(code) {
  const oauthClient = new google.auth.OAuth2({
    clientId: 'web app client id',
    clientSecret: 'web app client secret',
    redirectUri: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
  });
  return oauthClient.getToken(code) // the code that comes from ios
}
```